# Determine whether the limit exists and justify answer

Tags: real-analysis, limits

[image]

Usually for these types of questions, I use sequences of functions to show that the limit does not exist, but I don't think I can do this here? I feel like the limit should be zero, but I don't know how to show it?

Another example is calculate the limit as x tends to infinity of

[image]

Again, I feel the limit should be zero, but I don't know how to show it?

Can I use the sandwich theorem somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can be proven directly by the definiton of limit.

Fix $\epsilon >0$.

Let $x\in mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-1|<\epsilon$.

If $x$ is rational, then $|f(x)|=|x-1|<\epsilon$.

If $x$ is irrational, then $|f(x)|=|1-x|=|x-1|<\epsilon$.

Hence, for alll $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|x-1|$ implies $|f(x)|<0$. Hence the limit is $0$.

Second problem can be done analogously.